# What's the best way to write if/else if/else if/else in HIVE?

Tags: hive, hql

Hive uses IF(condition, expression, expression), so when I want to do if / else if / else if / else, I have to do:

```
IF(a, 1, IF(b, 2, IF(c, 3, 4)))
```

Is there a better way to do this that's more readable?

Looking for something similar to the standard

```
if (a) {
  1
} else if (b) {
  2
} else if (c) {
  3
} else {
  4
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use **Hive** Conditional `CASE WHEN` function for if-else scenario. The `CASE Statement` will provide you better readability with the same functionality.

```
CASE
  WHEN (condition1) THEN result1
  WHEN (condition2) THEN result2
  WHEN (condition3) THEN result3 
  WHEN (condition4) THEN result4
  ELSE result_default 
END AS attribute_name
```

Comment: cosmetic change needed, there is an extra ')' after the END

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve this using CASE WHEN statements.

```
CASE 
    WHEN a THEN 1
    WHEN b THEN 2
    WHEN c THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END AS attribute_name
```

For more information, refer official doc at  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle if else will be to write customize UDF for particular column.

Comment: IDK how this would work? If we have functions already then better to use it.

Comment: I would compromise code readability to speed of execution. UDF typically crossed boundaries - out of hive to udf program.  If possible in Hive try to accomplish it in Hive functions