# Insert data to table from another table containing null values and replace null values with the original table 1 values

Tags: hadoop, replace, hive, null

[image]

I want to match first column of both table and insert table 2 values to table 1 . But if Table 2 values are null leave table 1 vlaues as it is .I am using Hive to dothis .Please help.

Comment: You need to perform a `join` on the first column and then use a `case when then` Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472801/whats-the-best-way-to-write-if-else-if-else-if-else-in-hive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **`coalesce`** to get non null value to **populate `b column`** and **`case`** statement to make decision to **populate `c column`**.

***Example:***

```
hive> select t1.a,
      coalesce(t2.y,t1.b)b,
      case when t2.y is null then t1.c 
      else t2.z 
      end as c  
     from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.a=t2.x;

+----+-----+----+--+
| a  |  b  | c  |
+----+-----+----+--+
| a  | xx  | 5  |
| b  | bb  | 2  |
| c  | zz  | 7  |
| d  | dd  | 4  |
+----+-----+----+--+
```

Comment: thank you . How should the 'case when t2.y is null then t1.c  ' be changed if i have more columns like "d" , "f" ?