# How to split values from one string column

Tags: sql, hive

I have HIVE table with string column, in one column it have numbers of values and I would like to split those values into columns.
Here is sample column values.

[image]

End result should look like this 
[image]

I have used split function, since values in columns is not at same location ,  I am getting wrong values in columns, is there any function which takes value base on its tag value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **`regexp_extract`** function and keep matching **`regular expression`** and extract the value.

***`Regular expression:`***

```
lanes=>"(.*?)" //literal match for lanes=>" and capture until next following occurance " 
                and keep it in first capture group
```

***`Example:`***

```
with cte as (--sample data
    select stack(2,string('lanes=>"2","txt_mid"=>"0"'),
                    string('"is_in"=>"parksville"'))as(c1)) 
    select regexp_extract(c1,'lanes=>"(.*?)"',1)lanes,
            regexp_extract(c1,'"txt_mid"=>"(.*?)"',1)txt_mid 
        from cte;
```

***`Result:`***

```
lanes   txt_mid
2       0
```

In case if you want to **null** values for missing data records, then use [case-when-then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472801/whats-the-best-way-to-write-if-else-if-else-if-else-in-hive) statement to **check length** of the field if **0** then have `null` value for the record.