# Is there any way in HIVE to execute multiple scenarios based on the condition?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a situation like,

- if I have multiple records exists on column `X` in the table `TAB` then I need to run "Query #1"
- if I have only one record exists on column `X` in the table `TAB` then I need to run "Query #2"

The selected columns are same but the condition is different.

I tried with case clause but it did not worked.

Is there any way to achieve in Hive ?

Can we use ”Query #” in case clause? If yes please suggest an example.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include what you have tried so far in your question. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to write if/else if/else if/else in HIVE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472801/whats-the-best-way-to-write-if-else-if-else-if-else-in-hive)

Comment: I am not sure case clause will work. can we use any queries in case when any condition satisfied ? if yes please suggest the query.